# How to put multiple QPixmap in class which inherits from QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Tags: python, pyqt

Today , I got stuck with QPixmap. My class is inheriting from `QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem` and like in example below.

```
class graphicButton(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self):
        pixmapA = QtGui.QPixmap(r"img.png")

        QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem.__init__(self, pixmapA)
        self.setFlags(
            self.flags( )
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
        )
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("mouse left press")
            event.accept()
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print("mouse right press")
            event.accept()
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MidButton:
            print("mouse middle press")
            event.accept()
```

It's working fine, but what if I want to put more then one picture? In most cases which I found in google, you need to make multiple QGraphicsPixmapItems. In that case I can't anymore inherit from QGraphicsPixItem and I have to go for QGraphicsItem or am I missing something ?

Comment: How many images do you want to place? and how do you want them to be placed ?, that is, do you want it to be like a matrix? if so, how many rows or columns?

Comment: I want to make something like a human out of images which are going to be buttons. So I would say around 30-40 images which are going to be placed in shape of human in QGraphicsView.

Comment: I have never tried to use matrices in programming , so hardly can picture in my head how it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to load an image associated with its position, for example in the following case I place the images in the vertices of a pentagon:

```py
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsButton(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, name, pixmap, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsButton, self).__init__(pixmap, parent)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("mouse left press")
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print("mouse right press")
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MidButton:
            print("mouse middle press")
        print(self.name)
        super(GraphicsButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        # coordinates of the pentagon
        datas = [
            ("name1", "img0.png", QtCore.QPointF(0, -200)),
            ("name2", "img1.png", QtCore.QPointF(-190, -62)),
            ("name3", "img2.png", QtCore.QPointF(-118, 162)),
            ("name4", "img3.png", QtCore.QPointF(118, 162)),
            ("name5", "img0.png", QtCore.QPointF(190, -62)),
        ]
        for name, path, position in datas:
            item = GraphicsButton(name, QtGui.QPixmap(path))
            scene.addItem(item)
            item.setPos(position)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Btw, do you know how to query which item was clicked ? Something like 'event.clicked' or 'event.selected' , because I was looking hard into QEvent , but coudn't find anything useful.

Comment: @Vlad What do you want to happen when you press? How do you identify each item? Does each item have an id?

Comment: For now I just want it to print ( widget(image) which was clicked ) and in future change picture to different one , but for now , I want at least to understand how to identify what is clicked. About id of items , I read about it , but I thought I can just query simply what was clicked and do changes already on according to information it will return. I guess , it's impossible without giving each item an id ?

Comment: @Vlad What do you mean with `widget(image)` ?, you could place an example. When handling many elements an identifier must be given since that makes the work scalable

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, by widget(image) , i meant just image. In my head , since it's QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneItem , i said widget. By identifier you mean , id() or item.setData() ?

Comment: @Vlad What is "image"? Do you want to say the name of the file ?, for example in my code "img0.png", "img1.png", etc. By id I do not mean that, for example when you are born you are a human and how do we identify you? it is complicated without a name, a code, etc. That's what I mean by identifier. According to I presume that you want to make each image is a part of a human so a possible id would be the name of that part: "head", "leg", "hand", etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191697/discussion-between-vlad-and-eyllanesc).